# abbreviation in atom and sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

Is there a way to create my own abbreviations in atom and sublime like I can do with notepad++?

for example:
I have a chunk of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
blah... blah... blah...
</html>
```

With notepad++, I can just use shortcut to wrap it with abbreviation (e.g.: `html`) and next time I can just type `html` and expand it, it'll pop out all the code. Instead of all the `$>>>>**` like in Sublime.
I've read a dozen of manual online for sublime and atom but honestly, I still don't get it.

> **Update:**

Sublime > Tools > Developer > New Snippet...

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
Blah blah blah
</html>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>html-blah</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

So after successfully saved the snippet,  I type html-blah, there's no tab option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question (in the case of Sublime) is indeed Snippets as you've mentioned. They're a powerful way to include all sorts of text, including the ability to put placeholder fields that allow you to fill out more complex structures quickly and easily.

As outlined in your question the snippet you've defined will only have an effect in a Python source file because the `scope` is set to `source.python`.

Presuming that you want to use it to create a stub HTML document, you need to change the scope to `text.html` instead so that it will trigger from within HTML documents.

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
Blah blah blah
</html>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>html-blah</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

You can determine the scope to use by placing the cursor in a file that you want to trigger the snippet in and selecting `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` from the menu. That command shows you the full scope of the character at the cursor, and the more of it you include in your `scope` the more dialed in your snippet becomes.

For example, a scope of `text` works in all text files, `text.html` works in HTML based files like HTML and Markdown, and `text.html.basic` only works in HTML files but not Markdown (which are `text.html.markdown`).

Something to keep in mind is that the scope is based on the syntax that is set for the file, and by default all new tabs in Sublime are created using the syntax for Plain Text, so before the snippet will trigger you need to assign the appropriate syntax.

You can do that by:

- Saving the file with an appropriate extension
- Selecting the appropriate syntax from `View > Syntax` in the menu or by clicking on the type of the current file in the bottom right of the window (both open the same menu)
- Selecting the appropriate `Set Syntax:` command from the Command Palette.

For more information on the power of snippets I recommend the [Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/), which includes a [section on Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).

---

Note that there is already an existing snippet that ships with Sublime named `html` that does something similar to your example already.

Answer (score 1):

In sublime you need to install the Emmet package. It is easyer done by using the Package control. There are instructions on how to install it in the github repo: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions
Sorry for mistaking your issue with snippets :)

Comment: thank you, I don't think they're the same. Also, I've tried creating a new snippet in sublime and it just says error: no content for snippet even though I do have content for the new snippet

Comment: Mhm well I cant figure out what it is if not snippets. Based on your html above you can try this: create a snippet from the menu and replace all its contentents with this: `<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
blah... blah... blah...
</html>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>html</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
`

Comment: then save the file. Now when you type somewhere "html" and then press the tab button - the text from the snippet will appear.

Comment: It doesn't work: let me edit my question and show you what I've done so far.

Comment: In notepad++ you are wrapping from Plugins->Emmet->Wrap with abbreviation right?

Comment: Thank you. Then how do I add new abbreviations using the emmet package?